# How to change ImageView image after animation

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a simple Loading spinner view component that has two image assets. The first image is a spinner that should show and rotate while the component is "loading". The second image is a checkmark that should show without any animation when the "loading" has finished. I'd like to use one ImageView and just swap out the image asset when needed.

Here's the spinner image:

[image]

And here's the checkmark image:

[image]

I wrote a function to stop the animation and replace the image but when I call it this is what I see:

[image]

It looks like the image is getting changed but then the original image is getting redrawn.

Here's my function that starts the animation:

```
fun show() {
    rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)
    rotateAnimation!!.duration = 900
    rotateAnimation!!.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
    rotateAnimation!!.fillAfter = true
    mLoaderView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
}
```

And here's my function that stops the animation and changes the image:

```
private fun completeLoading() {
  rotateAnimation!!.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
        // not implemented
    }

    override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {
        // not implemented
    }

    override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
        mLoaderView.setBackgroundDrawable(Util.getLocalDrawable(mLoaderView.context, "icn_loading_error"))
    }
  })

  mLoaderView.clearAnimation()
}
```

How can I prevent the spinner image from getting drawn over the checkmark image?

Comment: Use `setImageDrawable` instead of `setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: yep that worked